# Get Value ID from <p:autoComplete>

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Get Value ID from `<p:autoComplete>`

this is my xhtml

```
<p:autoComplete 
dropdown="true" 
value="#{kabupatenBacking.selectedServiceLocation}" 
completeMethod="#{kabupatenBacking.autoComplete}" 
var="svl" 
itemLabel="#{svl.serviceLocationName}"
itemValue="#{svl.serviceLocationID}">
</p:autoComplete>
```

and this is my bean

```
private KabupatenEntity selectedServiceLocation;

public List<KabupatenEntity> autoComplete(String query)
{
    listServiceLocation = kabupatenRules.getServiceLocationByStatus();
    List<KabupatenEntity> queried = new ArrayList<KabupatenEntity>();
    String output = query.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + query.substring(1);
    for(KabupatenEntity kabupaten : listServiceLocation)
    {
        if(kabupaten.getServiceLocationName().contains(output))
        {
            queried.add(kabupaten);
        }
    }
    return queried;
}
```

and the problem is when i put component itemValue.autocomplete doesn't work
[image]

but when i remove ItemValue from `<p:autoComplete>` is work
[image]

but i need the value,how to i can get the value?

Thank You

Comment: `itemValue` in conjunction with `itemLabel` requires a collection like `List<T>` with an appropriate converter.

Comment: can you give me an example how to convert? @Tiny

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml